# Can't use Google Analytics Statistics Module - Impossible to login

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to use Google Analytics Statistics module but it won't accept my login credentials. I know they're correct because I tried them independently multiple times on the same browser to login to Google directly. I've also now try entering them 10's of times in the module and it never takes them. It takes my username but then rejects my password and gives the error 'Invalid Google Analytics login.'

I thought I found the solution, here, and it seemed to work for everyone else, but not for me. https://www.drupal.org/node/1370742

I did the patch - didn't help. I ran cron and clear caches a million times. I re-installed the module. I made sure I was logging in from the same browser where I was already logged into Google.

Note: Google never sent me an email, not once, asking me to confirm my login as the referenced article above suggests it would do.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this module is no longer supported and it appears many others also have problems authenticating with it. I recommend NOT using it. I also tried Google Analytics Statistics Counter module, and while I was able to get it setup it wasn't as intuitive as I'd hoped so I just used the 'Statistics' core module, even if it's not the 'preferred' choice performance-wise. For now it will do.